# Which JWT library is compatible with Xamarin.Forms(PCL)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, jwt

I want to decode my JWT token in my Xamarin.Forms(PCL) application. The nuget libraries I tried to install were `Xamarin.JOSE.JWT` and `jose-jwt` but it gives an error :

> Could not install package 'Xamarin.JOSE.JWT 1.0.3'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

I tried adding this with different project targets in PCL but it didn't work, there is no documentation available to which PCL profile this is compatible with.

I found `Portable.JWT` but it provides only 3 algorithms. I don't know if I can use it or not.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you contact the author and ask if they can add that profile in? If not, I generally reference it from source subrepo.